# How do I create an instance of a custom data type in OCaml?

Tags: types, ocaml

If I have a custom data type 'triple' as follows, how would I create an instance of it that I can use?

`type triple = int * int * int`

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an instance:

```
let my_instance = (1, 2, 3)
```

For what it's worth, your type is not a new type, it's just a handy abbreviation for the pre-existing type that's a tuple of 3 ints. A type declaration without a constructor is just an abbreviation, so not really what I'd call a "custom" type.

```
# ((1, 2, 3) : triple) = (1, 2, 3)
- : bool = true
```

I'm not sure this matters to you, but if you need a new type that's not compatible with any other, you need a constructor. Something like this:

```
type triple2 = T of int * int * int
```

Then you can make an instance like this:

```
let my_instance2 = T (1, 2, 3)
```

This new type `triple2` is not compatible with any other type (such as, say, `triple`):

```
# T (1, 2, 3) = (1, 2, 3)
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b * 'c
       but an expression was expected of type triple2
```